# compareTo() help (Diamond comparison project)

Tags: java, compareto

So I have a project to write a program that accepts info about diamonds and compares them. Here is the pertinant part of the prompt:

> The method compareTo() is written so that diamonds are ordered first by carot, then by clarity OR color, whichever is better for the particular diamond. Since there are 23 grades of color, but only 11 grades of clarity, regard the first two color grades as equal in grade to the first grade of clarity, the next two color grades equal in grade to the second grade of clarity, and so on. In comparing the codes for clarity, you will need a series of if statements.

I missed the lecture on interfaces and the compareto() stuff, but looking at the lecture notes I vaguely understand. Here's what I got so far:`enter code here`

```
public class Diamond {
    String stockNumber;
    double carot;
    String clarity;
    char color;
    String cut;
    public Diamond(String startStockNumber, double startCarot, String startClarity, String startCut) {
    stockNumber = startStockNumber;
    carot = startCarot;
    clarity = startClarity;
    cut = startCut;
}
    String getStock() {
        return this.stockNumber;
    }
    double getCarot() {
        return this.carot;
    }
    String getClarity() {
        return this.clarity;
    }
    char getColor(){
        return this.color;
    }
    String getCut() {
        return this.cut;
    }
    void tooString(){
      System.out.println(this+" is stock number "+this.stockNumber+" a "+this.carot+" carot diamond with "+this.clarity+" and a "+this.cut+" cut.");
    }
    int compareTo(Diamond other) {
        if (this.carot<other.carot){
            return -1;
        }
        else if (this.carot>other.carot){
            return 1;
        }
        else{

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: You could pre-calculate a "worth" value based on the information have and compare that ...

Comment: I don't really see what the question is, but if you want remarks or something, you could write    int comparTo(Object other)   and then cast the object diamond. Would make it a bit more flexible for future additions to the project

Comment: Do not confuse vegetables with Mass http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carat_(mass)

Comment: You may need to explain  in your own words, the logic of comparison. It's really hard to understand from the assignment wording.

Comment: You are in the right path. Now you need to code the case where the two diamonds have the same carats, which is described by your problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

So, you're writing a `compareTo()` function. That will order:

1. by Carat weight
2. by max( Clarity, Color) value.

The first is easy.

For the second, all you have to do is convert the Clarity & Color into numeric values to make the color/clarity tradeoff a simple numeric 'max()' operation. Then you compare the max() of these two, with the max() of the other diamond's.

You could break these bits out into a few functions:

```
protected int getColorValue();    // you implement this
protected int getClarityValue();  // you implement this

protected int getColorOrClarityValue() {
    int result = Math.max( getColorValue(), getClarityValue());
    return result;
}
```

And thus:

```
public int compareTo (Diamond o) {
    int comp = Double.compare( getWeight(), o.getWeight());
    if (comp != 0)
        return comp;
    comp = Integer.compare( getColorOrClarityValue(), o.getColorOrClarityValue());
    return comp;
}
```

This should be very easy to provide a clean solution.

Comment: Whenever refrenceing the first diamond(not the other/o diamond) do I need a 'this.'. I noticed you didn't use one for the getWeight(). Which means I don't need it for any of the getX() methods?

Comment: That's right.  You don't need `this.` in getters, because there's no other variable with the same name as whichever field you're getting.  You usually only need it with setters and constructors.

Comment: I only use `this` for assignments to member fields. This provides excellent clarity, and avoids needing some separate parameter & field-naming convention for setters. PS, feel free to accept or upvote my answer if it has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following 2 things to implemnet the order function you mentioned.

1. Make class Diamond implement **interface** `Comparable`

   `public class Diamond implements Comparable`
2. Make your own order function in `compareTo` method as **Thomas** metioned above.